# Is there a simple formula for an ellipse centered at an arbitrary point in the polar coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, ellipsoids

There exists an equation describing an ellipse in polar coordinates with the origin being at one focus. Is there a well-known one if the origin is at an arbitrary point?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The whole point of polar coordinates is that it's extremely biased to the origin.  A vertical line through the origin has equation $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Move it one unit to the right and it's suddenly $r = \sec \theta$.  So I would not expect any such formula to be simple.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I completely missed it was polar.  I'll delete my earlier comment.